# How to combine multiple INSERT queries with different WHERE syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to combine two queries :

```
INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUE (X) WHERE column2= 11

INSERT INTO table (column1) VALUE (Y) WHERE column2= 22
```

Comment: Neither of these queries are valid... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think you should go for update instead of insertion.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute an `UPDATE` query rather than `INSERT`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = x WHERE column2= 11;

UPDATE table SET column1 = y WHERE column2= 22;
```

This will return you the count of rows updated, if that count is `0` then you can do an `INSERT`, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES (x, 11);
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2) VALUES (y, 22);
```

**Update**

You can also combine two update query into one, with `CASE`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column1` = CASE
    WHEN column2 = 11 THEN x
    WHEN column2 = 22 THEN y
    ELSE `column1`
    END
WHERE id  in (11,22);
```

Comment: what if have two update queries : "UPDATE tablename SET column1='$last_ID' WHERE id=1"  and  "UPDATE tablename SET column1='$last_ID' WHERE id=3"    how to combine in one insert statement ?

Comment: @ArthurB added another query to combine two updates into single SQL.